# I created a questionnaire (5 questions) html with buttons of type=radio but it dont work well

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, input

## Problem

I created the tabular form with input as radio then add some java script function on click to increment the 7 th row of the table but when i kind a change the radio selection on the same row, it doesn't decrement the previous incremented value in the corresponding table row of the corresponding column and automaticaly sum up the corresponding  values of each of result of the columns of the 7 th row , in the 8 th row which has been applied a colspan

## Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    table {
      border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    
    table,
    th,
    td {
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
    
    th,
    td {
      padding: 10px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>a</th>
      <th>b</th>
      <th>c</th>
      <th>d</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input class="r1" id="r1" type="radio" name="1" value="1" onclick="updatePoints()">Option 1</td>
      <td><input class="r2" id="r2" type="radio" name="1" value="2" onclick="updatePoints1()">Option 2</td>
      <td><input class="r3" id="r3" type="radio" name="1" value="3" onclick="updatePoints2()">Option 3</td>
      <td><input class="r4" id="r4" type="radio" name="1" value="4" onclick="updatePoints3()">Option 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input class="r1" type="radio" name="2" value="1" onclick="updatePoints()">Option 5</td>
      <td><input class="r2" type="radio" name="2" value="2" onclick="updatePoints1()">Option 6</td>
      <td><input class="r3" type="radio" name="2" value="3" onclick="updatePoints2()">Option 7</td>
      <td><input class="r4" type="radio" name="2" value="4" onclick="updatePoints3()">Option 8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input class="r1" type="radio" name="3" value="1" onclick="updatePoints()">Option 9</td>
      <td><input class="r2" type="radio" name="3" value="2" onclick="updatePoints1()">Option 10</td>
      <td><input class="r3" type="radio" name="3" value="3" onclick="updatePoints2()">Option 11</td>
      <td><input class="r4" type="radio" name="3" value="4" onclick="updatePoints3()">Option 12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input class="r1" type="radio" name="4" value="1" onclick="updatePoints()">Option 13</td>
      <td><input class="r2" type="radio" name="4" value="2" onclick="updatePoints1()">Option 14</td>
      <td><input class="r3" type="radio" name="4" value="3" onclick="updatePoints2()">Option 15</td>
      <td><input class="r4" type="radio" name="4" value="4" onclick="updatePoints3()">Option 16</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input class="r1" type="radio" name="5" value="1" onclick="updatePoints()">Option 17</td>
      <td><input class="r2" type="radio" name="5" value="2" onclick="updatePoints1()">Option 18</td>
      <td><input class="r3" type="radio" name="5" value="3" onclick="updatePoints2()">Option 19</td>
      <td><input class="r4" type="radio" name="5" value="4" onclick="updatePoints3()">Option 20</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="total1"></td>
      <td id="total2"></td>
      <td id="total3"></td>
      <td id="total4"></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="4"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <script>
    function updatePoints() {
      var totalPoints = 0;
      var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"].r1:checked')
      checkboxes.forEach(function(checkbox) {
        if ('input[type="radio"].r1:checked') {
          totalPoints += parseInt(checkbox.value);
        } else {
          totalPoints -= parseInt(checkbox.value);
        }
      });

      document.getElementById("total1").textContent = totalPoints;
    }

    function updatePoints1() {
      var totalPoints = 0;
      var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"].r2:checked')
      checkboxes.forEach(function(checkbox) {
        if ('input[type="radio"].r2:checked') {
          totalPoints += parseInt(checkbox.value);
        } else {
          totalPoints -= parseInt(checkbox.value);
        }
      });

      document.getElementById("total2").textContent = totalPoints;
    }

    function updatePoints2() {
      var totalPoints = 0;
      var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"].r3:checked')
      checkboxes.forEach(function(checkbox) {
        if ('input[type="radio"].r3:checked') {
          totalPoints += parseInt(checkbox.value);
        } else {
          totalPoints -= parseInt(checkbox.value);
        }
      });

      document.getElementById("total3").textContent = totalPoints;
    }

    function updatePoints3() {
      var totalPoints = 0;
      var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"].r4:checked')
      checkboxes.forEach(function(checkbox) {
        if ('input[type="radio"].r4:checked') {
          totalPoints += parseInt(checkbox.value);
        } else {
          totalPoints -= parseInt(checkbox.value);
        }
      });

      document.getElementById("total4").textContent = totalPoints;
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are having some issues with not decrementing the previous values when swapping to a different row. I ended up with this solution:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        table {
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }

        table,
        th,
        td {
            border: 1px solid black;
        }

        th,
        td {
            padding: 10px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>a</th>
            <th>b</th>
            <th>c</th>
            <th>d</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="radio" name="1" value="1" onclick="updatePoints(this)">Option 1</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="1" value="2" onclick="updatePoints(this)">Option 2</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="1" value="3" onclick="updatePoints(this)">Option 3</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="1" value="4" onclick="updatePoints(this)">Option 4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="radio" name="2" value="1" onclick="updatePoints(this)">Option 5</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="2" value="2" onclick="updatePoints(this)">Option 6</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="2" value="3" onclick="updatePoints(this)">Option 7</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="2" value="4" onclick="updatePoints(this)">Option 8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="radio" name="3" value="1" onclick="updatePoints(this)">Option 9</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="3" value="2" onclick="updatePoints(this)">Option 10</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="3" value="3" onclick="updatePoints(this)">Option 11</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="3" value="4" onclick="updatePoints(this)">Option 12</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="radio" name="4" value="1" onclick="updatePoints(this)">Option 13</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="4" value="2" onclick="updatePoints(this)">Option 14</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="4" value="3" onclick="updatePoints(this)">Option 15</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="4" value="4" onclick="updatePoints(this)">Option 16</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="radio" name="5" value="1" onclick="updatePoints(this)">Option 17</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="5" value="2" onclick="updatePoints(this)">Option 18</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="5" value="3" onclick="updatePoints(this)">Option 19</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="5" value="4" onclick="updatePoints(this)">Option 20</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="total1"></td>
            <td id="total2"></td>
            <td id="total3"></td>
            <td id="total4"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <script>
        function updatePoints(clickedRadio) {
            var totalPoints = [0, 0, 0, 0]; // Initialize an array to store totals for each column
            var rows = document.querySelectorAll('tr:not(:last-child)'); // Exclude the last row

            rows.forEach(function (row, rowIndex) {
                var radios = row.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]');
                radios.forEach(function (radio, columnIndex) {
                    if (radio.checked) {
                        totalPoints[columnIndex] += parseInt(radio.value);
                    }
                });
            });

            // Update the total cells in the last row
            for (var i = 0; i < totalPoints.length; i++) {
                document.getElementById('total' + (i + 1)).textContent = totalPoints[i];
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

In my version, I made the following changes:

- Changed the function call from `onclick="updatePoints()"` to `onclick="updatePoints(this)"` to pass the clicked radio button element as an argument to the function.
- Simplified the JavaScript code by using loops to iterate through the rows and columns and calculate the total points for each column.
- Removed duplicate code for different radio button classes (r1, r2, r3, r4) and consolidated the logic into a single updatePoints function.
- Updated the way total points are displayed in the last row by using a loop to update the respective total cells.

This approach is more efficient, scalable, and easier to maintain compared to your initial code as well as should fix the issue you were running into earlier! I hope this helps!